# How to show the limit exist at $0$ and find its value?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, partial-derivative, epsilon-delta

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by

$$f (x,y) =\begin{cases} x^{2}y/(x^{6}+2y^{2}) &\text{ if }(x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ 
0&\text{ if }(x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}$$

Is this function differentiable at $(0,0)$?

I am trying to prove that it is differentiable by concluding the derivative is continous at $(0,0)$ that is showing the partial derivative of $x^{2}y/(x^{6}+2y^{2}) $ is $0$ at $(0,0)$

But how to prove that this limit exists using epsilon-delta? Could someone show the steps?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit at $(0,0) $ doesn't exist. If $y=x^3$, you get
$$
\frac {x^5}{x^6+2x^6 }=\frac {1}{3x},
$$ 
 so the limit blows up,